# SignalR - Message not received if roomName contains ' (apostrophe)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

Regarding signalR, if `roomName` is "Sam", no problems. If `roomName` is "Sam's" then it doesn't work. Seems like it would become Sam as the ' is finishing the string at that point (that's my guess)?

```
        // User send message from JS to controller
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessageAsync(string message, string roomName)
        {
            // Todo - Save message to dB
            
            // Send message back to client/JS
            await _chat.Clients.Group(roomName)
                .SendAsync("RecieveMessage", new { 
                    Text = Message.Text,
                    Name = Message.Name,
                    Timestamp = Message.Timestamp.ToString(" dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
                });
         }
```

For reference, this is where I Receive the Message in JS

```
        connection.on("RecieveMessage", function (data) {
            // Returns "name:", "text:" and "timestamp:" properties if roomName is "Sam", but not if roomName is "Sam's"
            console.log(data);
        })
```

Comment: Is your client a member of both group `Sam` and `Sam's`? Only members that have joined a group will receive messages sent to the group. Apostrophes are allowed according to this thread https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/345

Comment: Yes. The data is presented in the same way with `sam` and ```Sam's``` There logically shouldn't be any difference in the outcome.